# Rails & Image Science: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-science

I've problem with SocialNews framework from [NewsTrust](http://blog.newstrust.net/2011/08/open-source.html).
I use Ruby 187, Rails 2.3.11, DevKit, Visual C++ 2008 EE on Windows XP, when I run *ruby script/server* then I got following error: http://pastebin.com/LpNDRqcg.
The gemfile:

```
source :gemcutter
gem "rails", "2.3.11"
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
gem "mysql"
gem "aws-s3" ,'0.6.2'     #<--- if you use aws for image storage
gem "right_aws", '2.1.0'  #<--- if you use aws for image storage
gem "bj", '1.0.1'
gem "crack", '0.1.6'
gem "feed-normalizer", '1.5.2'
gem "hashie", '0.1.8'
gem "highline", '1.4.0'
gem "hoe", '2.3.3'
gem "hpricot", '0.8.4'
gem "httparty", '0.4.3'
gem "image_science"
gem "json", '1.2.0'
gem "libxml-ruby", '2.0.6'
gem "newrelic_rpm", '2.14.1'
gem "nokogiri", '1.4.4'
gem "rake", '0.9.0'
gem "RedCloth", '4.2.2'
gem "rspec", '1.2.9'
gem "ruby-debug", '0.10.4'
gem "RubyInline", '3.9.0'
gem "twitter", '0.8.4'
gem "twitter_oauth", '0.3.2'
gem "unicode", '0.4.0'
gem "will_paginate", '2.3.15'
gem "xml-simple", '1.0.15'
gem "ZenTest", '4.3.0'
gem "rdoc"

gem "koala"
gem "riddle"
gem "ruby-openid",'2.0.4'

# bundler requires these gems in all environments
# gem "nokogiri", "1.4.2"
# gem "geokit"

group :development do
  # bundler requires these gems in development
  # gem "rails-footnotes"
end

group :test do
  # bundler requires these gems while running tests
  # gem "rspec"
  # gem "faker"
end
```

Can anybody help me please? What I need to do? Thanks anyway..
By the way, how to convert ImageScience into Rmagick from this script (SocialNews framework)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the folder `C:\Documents and Settings\pije76\.ruby_inline`. And your stack is ancient.